# Mix command and variables in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, variables, script-fu

I need a very simple shell script that processes all images on a folder and changes its size. The image processing is done with gimp script-fu and the only thing that the shell script have to do is the for loop.

I made this:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir processed
for image in `ls`
do
    if [ $image != "script.sh" ]
    then
        if [ $image != "processed" ]
        then
            gimp -i -b '(let* ( (img (gimp-file-load 1 "1.jpg" "1.jpg")) (drw (gimp-image-get-active-drawable (car img))) ) (gimp-image-scale-full 1 400 300 3) (file-jpeg-save 1 (car img) (car drw) "processed/1.jpg" "1.jpg" 0.6 0 1 1 "" 3 0 0 2) (gimp-quit 0) )'
        fi
    fi
done
```

This code works but, in the script-fu code I put 1.jpg as the file name and, of course, I want that there appears the value of the $image variable. My shell scripting knowledge is limited and I'm lost with the way I have to put the variable inside the command.

Can you help me? Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for image in *` instead of `ls`.

To pass the variable to the Gimp script and preserve the quotes for Gimp, you'll need to use double quotes for the outer ones and escape the inner quotes:

```
gimp -i -b "(let* ( (img (gimp-file-load 1 \"$image\" \"$image\")) (drw (gimp-image-get-active-drawable (car img))) ) (gimp-image-scale-full 1 400 300 3) (file-jpeg-save 1 (car img) (car drw) \"processed/$image\" \"$image\" 0.6 0 1 1 "" 3 0 0 2) (gimp-quit 0) )"
```

You can also simplify your script:

```
mkdir processed
for image in *.jpg
do
    if [[ -f $image ]]
    then
        gimp ...
    fi
done
```

If you want to include more extensions:

```
for image in *.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,png,PNG}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem and your recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that may be more readable:

```
mkdir processed

gimp_script_template='(let* ( 
    (img (gimp-file-load 1 "%s" "%s")) 
    (drw (gimp-image-get-active-drawable (car img))) 
  ) 
  (gimp-image-scale-full 1 400 300 3) 
  (file-jpeg-save 1 (car img) (car drw) "processed/%s" "%s" 0.6 0 1 1 "" 3 0 0 2) 
  (gimp-quit 0) 
)'

for img in *; do
    [ ! -f "$img" ] && continue
    [ "$img" = "script.sh" ] && continue
    gimp_script="$( printf "$gimp_script_template" "$img" "$img" "$img" "$img" )"
    gimp -i -b "$gimp_script"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
"'(let* ( (img (gimp-file-load 1 "$image" "$image")) (drw (gimp-image-get-active-drawable (car img))) ) (gimp-image-scale-full 1 400 300 3) (file-jpeg-save 1 (car img) (car drw) "processed/$image" "$image" 0.6 0 1 1 "" 3 0 0 2) (gimp-quit 0) )'"
```